# Are there a JMX Prometheus exporter configuration file for Apache Ignite?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, ignite

I want to export cluster metrics to Prometheus. It's easy to achieve with javaagent but it needs a configuration file. I wonder whether it exists. Maybe someone have already done this work for Ignite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example of such configuration file in the GitHub repository of the JMX exporter for Prometheus: https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/6cc565e098071fcb0dc3f866819041d3ad28db9b/example_configs/ignite_2.6.0.yml